# IIS URL Rewrite - Redirect for subfolder to page

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I want to redirect any traffic on my website based on the following rule

https://www.test.com/abc  -> https://www.test.com/test1.aspx?c=abc

https://www.test.com/def  -> https://www.test.com/test1.aspx?c=def

The subfolder needs to be passed as a query string

I have tried this and it does not seem to work.

```
<rule name="Reditect1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)test.com/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{R:2}" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/test1.aspx?c={C:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after more research and trial and error I was able to figure it out. Here is how I have it setup now.

```
 <rule name="Redirect1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{R:0}" pattern="^(?!\s*$).+$"/>
                <add input="{R:0}" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/test1.aspx?c={C:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

**NOTE**
The rule was setup at the site level and not the server level in IIS. Hence, the pattern matching ignored the domain name.

**`^(.*)test.com/(.*) - tried matching a test.com after the actual qualified domain name. So www.test.com/test.com/abc would satisfy the condition and not www.test.com/abc`**

**Explanation**

The rule matches any URL that comes in - Pattern (.*)

The first condition ensures that anything following the qualified domain name has at least one non-space character

The second condition ensures there are no special characters in the part that is being parsed. This was my requirement.